# Working with dynamic jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I was wondering how to make this trigger work as I've tried all I can, but can't seem to find out the problem.

HTML

```
<div id="testFunc">Change AHref Class</div>
<a href="test.com" class="button" id="testLink">test</a>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    $("#testFunc").click(function () {
        $('#testLink').removeClass("button");
        $('#testLink').addClass("button2");
        return false;
    });
});

$(function () {
    $(".button2").click(function () {
        alert('test');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Somehow, the upon triggering testFunc which changes the source dynamically which causes the a href class to change from button to button2, it doesn't seem to register when i use button2 click.

Is there anyway to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$(document).on('click','.button2',function(){ code here });
```

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

Demo [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/FEr2s/) , [**Problem Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/FEr2s/1)

Comment: If so, how would i then go about using .attr? In most cases i use $(#div).attr, but in this case it doesn't work...

Comment: @user2587774 check updated answer with fiddle what u mean by `$(#div).attr`

Comment: I mean lets say my link says this <a href="test.com" class="button" data-node="123"></a> How would i go about selecting the value of data-node?

Comment: to get value use `$('a.button').data('node')`

Comment: I tried your solution on the jsFiddle and it works well....Unfortunately in my own script i get undefined :( Anyway of debugging it?? (Using $('a.button').data('node'))

Comment: I would love to, but it's not possible because it involves other library's such as fancybox, zCopy, and many others..Not including the values are generated off from PHP itself. But it's alright! thanks anyway!